# Kendo Grid column format not honored in editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/OJOmaS (or http://jsfiddle.net/xfxwukqf/)

Given:

```
field: "salary",
format: "{0:n0}", -this means 0 decimals
```

The Salary field is editable and always shows 0 decimals (whole numbers).

The user can enter 99.123456... and the field will show 99, so far so good.

**Problem:**

*When the user clicks on the field to edit again the field shows 99.12, why? Nowhere is the format for 2 decimals defined.*

*Second problem is that when I read the data the salary is also 99.12 (see screenshot attached). Whatever I change the format to the editor always displays 2 decimals. why?*

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Click in Salary Cell
2. Enter 99.1232343245
3. Click in Salary Cell again and notice the number 99.12 (also in console the value for salary is 99.12) yet the field format is n0 (no decimals

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it looks at thought the format is applied to the grid cell value. When in edit mode, the format does not seem to carry over to the editor for that cell. Perhaps this is controlled by a setting??

In the meantime, you can use the code below as a workaround and place a kendoNumericTextBox into an editor template for the cell and bind it to the container. You can specify no decimals in the edit mode. This may or may not be what you envisioned.
...

```
{ field: "name" },
    {
      field: "salary",
      format: "{0:n0}",
      editor:customSalaryEdior
    }
```

...

```
function customSalaryEdior(container, options) {
    $('<input id="' +  kendo.guid() + '" name="Salary" data-bind="value:salary">')
          .appendTo(container)
          .kendoNumericTextBox({
              decimals: 0,
              min: 0,
              format: 'n0'
           });
}
```